# Mysql: How can i use LIKE in a left join query?

Tags: mysql

[image: This is the query]
These are my tables. The first one is the sp_archive and the second one is the account table.
[image]
[image]
The output should be titles with the keyword Prop. When i use the sql code above there's an output but it's wrong

Comment: give us more information. what should be the result, what is the actual result and what is the structure of your tables

Comment: Add WHERE caluse

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong.

Replace WHERE to AND at the bottom line

Comment: The WHERE clause should precede GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

Just as @PaulCampbell said, the AND clause at the end should be a WHERE clause and it should be before the group by clause